# Passing resolved data to child state in Ui-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So, I have a state where the resolve spits out an array which shows correctly on the frontend.

But I can't seem to be able to pass the parent resolve data to the child state.

```
$stateProvider.state('berliner', {
  url: '/berlinerliste',
  params : {search: 'Berliner 2017'},
  resolve: {
    fair: function(SearchService, $stateParams) {
      return SearchService.getAllExhibitors($stateParams.search);
    }
  },
  views: {
    'header': {   
      templateUrl: 'header.htm'   
    },
    'main':{    
      templateUrl: 'bl2017.htm',
      controller: function($scope, fair){
        $scope.fair = fair;
        console.log($scope.fair);
      }    
    }
  }
})

.state('berliner.exhibitor', {
  url: '/{id}', 
  resolve: {
    exhibitor: function($stateParams, fair) {
      var slug = $stateParams.id;
      return slug;
    }
  },
  views: {
    'header': {   
      templateUrl: 'header.htm'  
    },
    'wop':{ 
      templateUrl: 'exhibitor.htm',
      controller: function($scope, exhibitor, $filter){
        $scope.fairs = $scope.fair;
        console.log($scope.fair);
        $scope.chosenexhibitor = $filter("filter")($scope.fairs, {'slug':exhibitor}, true);
       console.log($scope.chosenexhibitor);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

All the console log come out undefined.

What am I missing?

### PLUNKR

Here's [a Plunkr to examplify the issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/KnyoKZI4AG3ckoLXNELt?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that the concept should work.. just:

> controller belongs to **view**. not to all `views: {}`

E.g. this *(wrong)*

```
// each view can have controller, 
// but views : {} property 'controller' is not used at all
views: {
    'header': {   
      templateUrl: 'header.htm'  
    },
    'wop':{ 
      templateUrl: 'exhibitor.htm',
    },
    controller: function($scope, exhibitor, $filter){
      $scope.fairs = $scope.fair;
      console.log($scope.fair);
      $scope.chosenexhibitor = $filter("filter")($scope.fairs, {'slug':exhibitor}, true);
      console.log($scope.chosenexhibitor);
    }
```

should be adjusted as that:

```
 views: {
    'header': {   
      templateUrl: 'header.htm'  

      controller: function($scope, exhibitor, $filter){
        $scope.fairs = $scope.fair;
        console.log($scope.fair);
        $scope.chosenexhibitor = $filter("filter")($scope.fairs,  {'slug':exhibitor}, true);
        console.log($scope.chosenexhibitor);
      }
    },
    'wop':{ 
      templateUrl: 'exhibitor.htm',
      controller: ...
```

There is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/F3iDnf4p2YJxdHJPieES?p=preview), how

- parent does resolve
- child view's controller consumes it

states:

```
  .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      resolve: {
        example: ['$timeout', function($timeout){
            return $timeout(function(){
              return {x: 1}
            },100)
        }],
      },
  })
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
  })
```

child controller

```
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', 'example', function ($scope, example) { 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(example));
}])
```

Check it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/F3iDnf4p2YJxdHJPieES?p=preview)

Comment: Now the controllers seem to work (console logs coming out undefined), but still no data gets passed...

Comment: Let me build one, is kinda complex. On the meantime: [link](http://cccctanger.com/discovery/exhibitors/#!/berlinerliste)

Comment: I built one for you.. simplified, showing in action how parent resolve work with child controller as consumer.. hope that helps

Comment: I couldn't replicate it on my example :/ I managed to build one where the problem is shown! [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/KnyoKZI4AG3ckoLXNELt?p=preview)

Comment: I played with your plunker ... and it is working.. not sure what I should do for you. seems .. you've made it... or?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150327/discussion-between-eric-mitjans-and-radim-kohler).